# Add own authentication to UserService for AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, openid

I am using UserService to allow my users to register and login.

We find that users for some reason would like to create a login on our own site without using their existing credentials.

I know UserService supports Google Friend Authentication and we can use Yahoo & other openids. However, I would like to know if we can add our authentication mechanism without becoming implementing as an open-id provider/producer.

If becoming a openid provider is only viable option, are there any recommended libraries for AppEngine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you do this depends entirely on how you've built your authorization system. Using the Users API directly, your only options are to use OpenID or Google Accounts (and only one per app, at any one time, not both). If you want more flexibility, you will need to build your own authorization subsystem, or use an existing one, which abstracts away different auth providers. See, for instance, [webapp2's auth module](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/auth.html).

Comment: I am accepting this an answer. Just to add a note, you can both use Federated Login (OAuth) and Google Accounts which is beta. After some research, the only easy way is to implement oauth provider (Server). Thanks.

Comment: @user943065 Yes - I meant to say openid, not oauth.